# How to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML without the wrapper div?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

My HTML content is coming from an API (Gatsby in this case) so I'm using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as recommended. The thing is, it messes with my styling, specifically with grids. I have a html markup like this:

```html
<article>
    <h2>Title of the post<h2>
    <small>Date of the post</small>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }} />
</article>
```

This `<article>` tag contains a `display: grid` style. But all the content inside that div is taking precious space making it hard to style (also it's not an useful div!). All the important html is inside but I want to get rid of the actual `<div>` tag. Is there any way to do it?

Note: I already tried to `{post.html}` it directly but it's encodedURI which can't be decoded.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you put `Title` and `Date` inside `post.html`?

Comment: If I understood you right I couldn't because every prop is given to me from graphql so title and date are parsed from a markdown and given separately (so I can rearrange in HTML) - then everything else is post.html (the rest of that markdown). It's really messy that dangerouslySetInnerHTML needs its own div.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [react docs for dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

> you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html key...

So there's nothing stopping you from forming your own html string from different parts of your graphql query like so:

```
const createFullPostMarkup = () => {
    return { __html: `<h2>Title of the post</h2><small>Date of the post</small>${ post.html }` }
}
```

And then setting it later as inner html on your article like this:

```
<article dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createFullPostMarkup()} />
```

Remember, this is just an object with a `__html` key. You can put anything in there.

Note: What I think you might be after is described by this open [feature request](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12014). For your use case, i think the above solution works perfectly. But if you're still not satisfied, check out the discussion in the linked issue.

Comment: Nice "hack", gonna try it. Thank you!

Comment: Although it works for my specific problem, it will of course still create a new `<article>` below `<article>` which isn't semantic at all. So I'm still looking for a semantic way of doing it.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but the above should replace your existing html markup so you only end up with one `<article>`.

Comment: In all my examples it still duplicates `article` tag so unfortunatelly it doesn't. Did you test on a gatsby project?

Comment: Yes I did. So you are getting two articles with the exact same content?

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Comment: No it's still the same. I tested on a recent gatsby project and it doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
/**
 * Load CSS file in parallel vs a blocking <link /> tag
 *
 * @param {string} fontUrl The raw font URL
 */
const LoadCSSFile = ({ fontUrl }) => {
  // hilariously bad hack to get around React's forced wrapper for dangerouslySetInnerHTML
  // @see https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12014#issuecomment-434534770
  let linkStr = '</style>';
  linkStr += `<link rel="preload" href="${fontUrl}" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" />`;
  linkStr += `<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="${fontUrl}"></noscript>`;
  linkStr += '<style>';

  return <style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: linkStr }} />;
};
```

This will output as:

```
<style></style>
<link ... />
<noscript><link ... /></noscript>
<style></style>
```

Definitely not the most elegant solution but it should accomplish what you need until React supports dangerouslySetInnerHTML on fragments.

Comment: A developer's mind works in mysterious ways! I am using this.